# push array value in variable using java script

Tags: javascript

I have one string, i want to split this and push it in variable.
i am try to push array value in variable result 
this is what i tried.

```
var region = "Rajkot,Jamnagar,Surat";
var result;
var array = region.split(',');
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++ )
            {
                alert(array[i]);
                result.push(array[i]);
            }
```

but its returning error result.push is not a function.
how to push value on variable
and i am trying to alert this result variable. 
please solve my query.
thanks.

Comment: `var region = "Rajkot,Jamnagar,Surat"; var result = region.split(',');` should be enough.

Comment: Quick question - why not just do `result = region.split(",");`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should initialize the `result` variable as

```
var result = [];
```

So your final code would be:

```
var region = "Rajkot,Jamnagar,Surat";
var result = [];
var array = region.split(',');
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++ ){
   alert(array[i]);
   result.push(array[i]);
}
```

But `split()` already returns an array, so your `for` might be unnecessary, unless you wish to do business logic with the elements of the array before adding them to the results.

Answer (score 3):

i think you need to initialize result as an array

ie `var result = [];`

Answer (score 2):

Why are you pushing the array? `split` returns an array.

```
var region = "Rajkot,Jamnagar,Surat";
var result = region.split(','); // This is already an array
for (var i in result) {
    alert(result[i]);
}
```

See [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VR5QX/2/).

Answer (score 1):

In order to use the functions in the `Array` prototype, you'll need to actually have an array. Right now, you have a `result` variable which is undefined (and cannot therefore support `push`).

In order for it to work, you need to make sure that the type of your variable is actually an array. This can be done like this:

```
var result = [];
```

(always remember to initialize your arrays if you are not using a function to do so)

Comment: +1 for actually saying the value of `result` was `undefined`.  It's always a more helpful answer that not only suggests the correction but also explains what the OP sees.

Comment: @RayToal: some people prefer direct results over explanations. However, being provided both, whilst a bit longer, covers all bases. ^_^